# 'int' object is not iterable while using zip in python

Tags: python, iterable, python-zip

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
n = len(a)
d = 3
c = []
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i,n):
    for k in range(j,n):
        for x,y,z in zip(a[i],a[j],a[k]):
            print(x,y,z)
```

> Error : Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 8, in 
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

It works when I convert list object to string but not working in int.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. zip takes iterables...strings are iterable, instead integers aren't

Comment: it definately wont. Because indexing will give back the object and not an iterable container here. unless you call it like this: `zip([a[i]], [a[j]], [a[k]])`.

Comment: @Neeraj  I want to make subset list of a of 3 length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because indexing will give back the object and not an iterable container here. unless you call it like this: `zip([a[i]], [a[j]], [a[k]])`.

```
a = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10]
n = len(a)
d = 3
c = []
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i,n):
    for k in range(j,n):
        for x,y,z in zip([a[i]], [a[j]], [a[k]]):
            print(x,y,z)
```